# How to get public key from arraybuffer?`

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to get public key from arraybuffer.

[image]

so, I tried this :

```js
let enc = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
    let arr = new Uint8Array([3, 101, 120, 26, 14, 172, 115, 184, 5, 99, 172, 149, 51, 147, 202, 196, 113, 158, 195, 161, 238, 122, 0, 7, 89, 33, 199, 156, 237, 213, 187, 29, 125]);

    console.log(enc.decode(arr));
```

But, It doesn't throw expected resuslt.

result should be something like this `026477115981fe981a6918a6297d9803c4dc04f328f22041bedff886bbc2962e01`

Comment: What is the expected result? What debugging steps have you done?

Comment: I'm expecting public key from it.

Comment: Could you please write the expected result

Comment: Yes, and what is the ***value*** of the resultant "public key" you are expecting to be produced/generated? When I run this code in the console this is the result: `'\x03ex\x1A\x0E�s�\x05c��3���q�á�z\x00\x07Y!ǜ�ջ\x1D}'`. Is this unexpected?

Comment: You can't convert this to UTF-8.  This is a binary byte array, and it needs to remain a byte array.

Comment: @DrewReese the result should be something like this = `026477115981fe981a6918a6297d9803c4dc04f328f22041bedff886bbc2962e01`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone pointed out, the binary data cannot be decoded as utf-8 since some bytes would just not be valid utf-8. Based on your expected output, I think you want your binary data to be converted to an hex encoded string. A 'hex' string is where a single byte of information is represented in a string using two hexadecimal characters each between `0 to f` representing 0-15 counting in hexadecimal.

You can do such conversion using a function like this:

```
function toHex(buffer) {
    return Array.from(buffer)
        .map(byte => byte.toString(16).padStart(2, '0'))
        .join('');
}

let arr = new Uint8Array([
  3, 101, 120, 26, 14, 172, 115, 184, 5, 99, 172, 149,
  51, 147, 202, 196, 113, 158, 195, 161, 238, 122, 0,
  7, 89, 33, 199, 156, 237, 213, 187, 29, 125
]);

console.log(toHex(arr));
// prints
// '0365781a0eac73b80563ac953393cac4719ec3a1ee7a00075921c79cedd5bb1d7d'
```

Another common format for encoding binary data in string is base64. Base64 encoded data takes less space than hex, so do consider using base64 if your implementation and other factors allow it.